# Nginx configuration issue with https on windows

Tags: reactjs, nginx, https, configuration

I am trying to deploy my react app to nginx server. Http configuration is working fine, but https is not working. Here is my configuration file.

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}  

http {
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name example.com;
      root D:\\path-to-build\\build;
      index index.html;
     

      location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
      }
      }

    server {
        listen              443 ssl;
        server_name         example.com;
        keepalive_timeout   70;

        ssl_certificate     C:\\Certbot\\live\\domain\\fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key C:\\Certbot\\live\\domain\\privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        #...
        access_log D:\\path-to-log\\access.log;
        error_log D:\\path-to-log\\error.log;
        root D:\\path-to-build\\build;
        index index.html;
        location / {
          try_files $uri /index.html =404;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "but https is not working", there is an error? can't connect?

Comment: When i am trying to hit using https.example.com URL, it is giving error "The connection has timed out". Is my server configuration is valid or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration is correct only, but in my server machine 443 post is not open for outside. That's the reason I am getting connection timed out.

Answer (score 0):

Your config file looks good. But in your SSL server config i do not see any reference to `root` or `index` directives.

Add this to your SSL server as well:

```
root D:\\path-to-build\\build;
index index.html;
```

Also as the error implice ("The connection has timed out") can you please try changing the value to `keepalive_timeout   70s;` Note that the default value is 75 seconds.

Comment: I tried adding that also in ssl server, but then also it is not working.

Comment: Can you try changing the keepalive_timeout to work with seconds? i'm not sure what 70 means there but it will be safer to use 70s :)

Comment: Same issue after increasing the timeout also.

Comment: can you try with only `TLSv1.2` in `ssl_protocols` or just `TLSv1.1`?

Comment: also can you please run nginx -V and comment here with the output, it will print NGINX version, compiler version and configure parameters.

Comment: nginx version: nginx/1.18.0
built by cl 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
TLS SNI support enabled

Comment: configure arguments: --with-cc=cl --builddir=objs.msvc8 --with-debug --prefix= --conf-path=conf/nginx.conf --pid-path=logs/nginx.pid --http-log-path=logs/access.log --error-log-path=logs/error.log --sbin-path=nginx.exe --http-client-body-temp-path=temp/client_body_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=temp/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=temp/fastcgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=temp/scgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=temp/uwsgi_temp --with-cc-opt=-DFD_SETSIZE=1024 --with-pcre=objs.msvc8/lib/pcre-8.44 --with-zlib=objs.msvc8/lib/zlib-1.2.11 --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module

Comment: --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-mail --with-stream --with-openssl=objs.msvc8/lib/openssl-1.1.1f --with-openssl-opt='no-asm no-tests -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501' --with-http_ssl_module --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_module